# Does matlab build-in max-flow algorithm support undirected graph?

Tags: matlab, graph, max-flow

I am using the matlab build-in max-flow algorithm for undirected graph. Every edge is replaced by two directed edge with same capacity 1. However, it encounters an error:
"Reciprocal edges are not allowed in maxflow algorithms".  Does matlab  build-in max-flow algorithm support undirected graph?